# sed replacement assistance with url

Tags: xml, sed, plex

I'd need the below xml data to be parsed by sed inside my variable and return `https://192-168-1-123.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:32400`

I am using a variable called PLX_IP:

```
IPADDRESS=$(
  curl -b plexcookie.txt "https://plex.tv/pms/resources.xml?includeHttps=1&X-Plex-Token=${PLX_TOK}" | \
  sed 's/.*uri=\"\([^\"]*\)\"\slocal.*/\1/g' | \
  tail -n 5)



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MediaContainer size="6">
  <Device name="Test" product="Plex Media Server" productVersion="1.14.1.5490-33830be0b" platform="Android" platformVersion="8.0.0" device="SHIELD Android TV" clientIdentifier="adfafasdfasdfasdfsdf" createdAt="1548647140" lastSeenAt="23424324" provides="server" owned="1" accessToken="asdfasdfadfadsfadsfa" publicAddress="11.111.11.11" httpsRequired="1" synced="0" relay="1" publicAddressMatches="1" presence="1">
    <Connection protocol="https" address="192.168.1.123" port="32400" uri="https://192-168-1-123.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:32400" local="1"/>
    <Connection protocol="https" address="11.111.11.11" port="11111" uri="https://11-111-11-11.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:11111" local="0"/>
  </Device>
  <Device name="Firefox" product="Plex Web" productVersion="3.91.0" platform="Firefox" platformVersion="65.0" device="OSX" clientIdentifier="adfafasdfasdfasdfsdf" createdAt="asdf" lastSeenAt="" provides="client,player,pubsub-player" owned="1" publicAddress="11.111.11.11" publicAddressMatches="1" presence="1" accessToken="asdfasdfadfadsfadsfa">
    <Connection protocol="https" address="192.168.1.123" port="32400" uri="https://192-168-1-123.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:32400" local="1"/>
    <Connection protocol="https" address="11.111.11.11" port="11111" uri="https://11-111-11-11.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:11111" local="0"/>
  </Device>
</MediaContainer>
```

This only returns the last 5 lines, but I need just the `https://192-168-1-123.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:32400`

Any help is very much appreciated. I know an xml parser is probably better for this but i'm developing this on an embedded box and can't afford the additional overhead

Comment: Use a proper XML parser, sed is not meant for it.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Added desired output, thank you!

Comment: `IPADDRESS=$(
  curl -b plexcookie.txt "https://plex.tv/pms/resources.xml?includeHttps=1&X-Plex-Token=${PLX_TOK}" | 
  grep 'local="1"' | 
  sed 's/.*uri=\"\([^\"]*\)\"\slocal.*/\1/g' | 
  tail -n 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *oguzismail* wrote, this is best done with an *xmlparser*, but even with simple tools you can solve this problem:

**1. grep all interessting lines from xml file**

```
grep 'local="1"' file.xml
```

*this produce:*

```
   <Connection protocol="https" address="192.168.1.123" port="32400" uri="https://192-168-1-123.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:32400" local="1"/>
   <Connection protocol="https" address="192.168.1.123" port="32400" uri="https://192-168-1-123.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:32400" local="1"/>
```

**2. extract uri's form this lines**

```
sed "s/.*uri=\"\([^\"]*\)\"\slocal.*/\1/g"
```

*this produce:*

```
https://192-168-1-123.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:32400
https://192-168-1-123.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:32400
```

**3. the uri's are indentical and you can take one of it (e.g. the last)**

```
tail -1
```

*this produce*

```
https://192-168-1-123.385ualfkj3fakedlajkf353029485234.plex.direct:32400
```

**4. concatenate all parts together**

```
grep 'local="1"' file.xml | sed "s/.*uri=\"\([^\"]*\)\"\slocal.*/\1/g" | tail -1
```

And you get what you wish!

Comment: We are getting close, I updated the original inquiry to make more clear